# How is the correct way to pay my customers

Tags: e-commerce, payment-gateway, payment

I want to create a platform where I have 2 kinds of users, Seller and Buyer.

Let's imagine that the Seller is selling a $10 product and I need get 10% of the value to me. Which is the correct way to do that transaction? The buyer need to pay to my account and I transfer the money to the seller after that? How can I do that transaction in a secure way for me and my customers? I need use gateways like Stripe or Paypal for that?

How the majority of platforms pay me with only my bank data? In platforms like Amazon, Shpfy... I think they don't have a person that do manual transfers every day for each seller.

Answer (score 0):

You need [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/connect) that allows you to work with merchants and payout them. Let me know, if you have a question with Stripe and Stripe Connect.